# .htaccess file blocks css, js but how?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file inside an existing project folder. The code for the .htaccess file is below.

```
# Use PHP54 Single php.ini as default
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^users/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ users/index.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ users/$1 [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/users/$1 -f
#RewriteRule .* users/$1 [L]
#Options -Indexes
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^[!/.]*([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]



#<FilesMatch "\.(?i:vcf)$">
#  ForceType application/octet-stream
#  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
#</FilesMatch>

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, skip next two rules
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
#
# Requested resource does not exist, do rewrite if it exists in /users
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/users/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/users/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) users/$1 [L]
#
# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) users/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

So what happens it, when I try to open the project in url at localhost

```
    http://localhost/projectfolder
```

it opens the index file without any javascript and css. Also the links to other pages do not open and the error message shows as -"Object not found". So I can only view index.php with out css and js files.

But when I remove / rename the .htaccess file, all works fine. So there must be something in this file which blocks all css, js files. So I am not asking for all the rules of writing a .htaccess file, I just need to know which line of code is blocking  the files and how can I edit them, so it will not block any file wile working in localhost.

Note:- This question I am asking only for my knowledge. As I have written, if I remove the file then its working fine. But still I want to know which line of code is blocking the access to files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this rule is not doing what you think it should be doing:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
```

Replace this with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Also you might be using relative links for css/js/images which will also cause 404 after rewriting to `/users/`. You have 2 options to fix that:

1. use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. You can try adding this in your page's HTML header:

   ```
   <base href="/" />
   ```

Comment: yes, when I replaced that its working. the problem is in those 3 lines. thnks for finding it..